# Using .update() to populate dictionary with another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to populate a new dictionary (`outer_dict`) in the following way, but I am having a hard time understanding how to use `.update()` (I'm assuming this is a direct way to preceed, though I am not sure about it).

Assume that I have:

```
file = "A_file"
inner_dict = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}
```

and that in the end I would like to get:

```
{"A_file":{1: "one"}, "A_file":{2: "two"}, "A_file":{3: "three"}}
```

So basically I want to  repeat the same key over all the outer dictionary entries.
This clearly does not work because I am overwriting the items:

```
for item in inner_dict.items():
        outer_dict[file_name]=item
print(outer_dict)
```

I checked the documentation on `update()` but it is not clear to me how to use it here. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Dictionary keys *must be unique*. You can't repeat the key. All that happens is that you replace the value associated with the key.

Comment: @OP - consider what happens when you write `outer_dict["A_file"]` ... what would it return if keys are non-unique? Perhaps it's time to take a step back and explain what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: the outcome mentioned doesn't make sense.
guess - probably you just want  `outer_dict = {"A_file": inner_dict}`

Comment: totally right.. I am ttrying to address the final task I am trying to achieve wrongly.. it seems it is not possible to delete the question though..

Comment: I can try to rephrase it, although the question would become quite different

Comment: @Stezzo: I'd say that's fine in this case. There isn't really anything useful for future visitors here (that dictionaries must have unique keys has been answered before, and better).

Comment: ok, apologies for the confusion, if possible I would close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible: dictionary can't have two same keys (here `"A_file"`).
(here you've got : `{'A_file': (3, 'three')}` because each statement will replace the former).